# _http_server.js:192 throw new RangeError(`Invalid status code: ${statusCode}`);

Tags: node.js, http, express, redis

This is my code:

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var redis = require('redis');
var url = require('url');
var client = redis.createClient().setMaxListeners(0);

var app = express();
app.set('port', 3000);

app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
  var key = url.parse(req.url).pathname;
  client.on('connect', function() {
    console.log('connected to redis!');
  });
  client.get(key, function(err, reply) {
    if( reply == null) {
      client.set(key, 1);
      client.expire(key, 300);
      res.send('1');
    }
    else {
      client.incr(key, function(err, reply) {
        console.log('increment value: ' + reply);
        res.sendStatus(reply);
      });
    }
  });

});


http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log('listening');
});
```

This is my output when I run the file ($ node test.js):
I tried this on my ubuntu machine and it perfectly works. This is what I get on my mac. Could someone explain me why this is happening. Any help would be appreciated.

```
listening
increment value: 2
_http_server.js:192
    throw new RangeError(`Invalid status code: ${statusCode}`);
    ^

RangeError: Invalid status code: 2
    at ServerResponse.writeHead (_http_server.js:192:11)
    at ServerResponse._implicitHeader (_http_server.js:157:8)
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.end (_http_outgoing.js:559:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (/Users/sharath/webapps/docker/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:209:10)
    at ServerResponse.sendStatus (/Users/sharath/webapps/docker/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:346:15)
    at Command.callback (/Users/sharath/webapps/docker/test.js:24:13)
    at normal_reply (/Users/sharath/webapps/docker/node_modules/redis/index.js:714:21)
    at RedisClient.return_reply (/Users/sharath/webapps/docker/node_modules/redis/index.js:816:9)
    at JavascriptRedisParser.returnReply (/Users/sharath/webapps/docker/node_modules/redis/index.js:188:18)
    at JavascriptRedisParser.execute (/Users/sharath/webapps/docker/node_modules/redis-parser/lib/parser.js:415:12)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Http response statuses should be integers. It cannot be strings, objects, array or like that and should begin from 100.

From your code i see that you try to do

`res.sendStatus(reply);`

Check reply variable. From redis incr response im thinking it's string "OK".

Which is bad.. So to fix it just use

`res.sendStatus(reply ? 200 : 500);`

Also check this.

http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.sendStatus

And this

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

**EDIT**

If you need to send some JSON or data into front-end just do like this

`res.json({thisIsMyNumber: reply});`

or

`res.send({thisIsMyNumber: reply});`

Hope this helps.

Comment: The value is `2` and is evident from the error message. This makes sense because they are incrementing from an initial value of 1.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes  stars from 100..Just change reply to be 200...or 400 or whatever..But not less than 100

Comment: Actually I am implementing a very simple visitor counter. Here I am trying to count the number of visits in last 5mins aggregated by the URI. I have tried the same code on ubuntu and I get the correct output. i.e. 
1
2
3 ... the number of visits in last five minutes.
But on my mac, I am getting this error.
How do I display this number on my page if this is not the correct method? I am sorry this is my first time with node.

Comment: @MykolaBorysyuk I know that, but what I'm trying to say is that the value of `reply` is `2`, not `'OK'` or anything else.

Comment: Can you try to res.sendStatus(101) instead res.sendStatus(reply)

Comment: I should also point out that you *can* send a string for the status code, since node core implicitly converts it to a number. So you could use `'200'` for example in addition to `200`.

Comment: Yep you can...if string is correct integer.. But if string is "im string 200x" it will be error.

Comment: I understand where I am going wrong. But for my application I need to display the count value. It could be a string, which does not make any difference to my application, but it has to show the count value. It can be any value between 1 and 100 or even more. It just represents the number of visits. 
I clearly understand what I am doing is wrong. Could you guys suggest a different method to do this! My count value is stored in the "reply" variable.

Comment: Actually yes. That was my mistake. I got a warning asking me to use status code for this when I did res.send(1). That is when I started using res.sendStatus. But I get it now. I am using res.send(string) and it works perfectly now. 
I am really thankful to all your suggestions. Sorry for being so dim. I just started working on this.

Comment: Cool. Glad answer helps you.